Update Link using OfficeScript
I have a VBA macro created for excel where formula have linkage to external links so I use
Myworkbook.UpdateLink Name:=Myworkbook.LinkSources

Now we are planning to move the macro to OfficeScript so that it can be triggered automatically via power automate cloud.
Was able to move all the codes, except update link. How can I use update links in OfficeScript?

Do you mean office scripts? I have no idea what app script is.

Yes, office script. My bad for typo
